# Listener for datepicker validation not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker field that my user insert a date. My listener send the user's date to a function to do a validation of this date and send a message and release a button do save this new Status. The problems:

- Not execute the function, instantly on user's insert date

The function execute ever the user insert other date or click inside my field. Someone have any idea how i solve this?

```
$("#date_field").on("propertychange click change input paste keyup", function() {
    var size = $(this).val().length;
    if (size == 10) {
        var val = valiDate();
        if (val) {
            $("#id_save_status").prop("disabled", false);
            $("label[name='err_date']").css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $("#id_save_status").prop("disabled", true);
            $("label[name='err_date']").css('display', 'block');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `valiDate()` return?

Comment: Return a boolean, if validate the date of user's insert, is true. But my problems is with my `$("#date_field").on('...', function ()) [...];`, not execute  instantly on user's insert date.

Comment: What is `#date_field`? An input box or a dynamic field? I can only assume from the tags that it is a jQuery UI Datepicker field.

Comment: `#date_field` is my input field who allocate the date.

Comment: Is your input `<input id="date_field" type="date">`, because I have tried with a `console.log('test date');` on change function and it works fine.